# Problemas al asignar un callback a evento onclick

Tags: javascript

Buenas tardes agradezco de ante mano a quien me pueda ayudar, requiero llamar una función desde Javascript que contiene un mensaje, cada vez que oprima el botón del formulario. Pero me encontré con dos problemas 
1. el mensaje aparece al cargar la pagina 
2. el botón no esta llamando la función.
y no entiendo porque este comportamiento me gustaría que me explicaran mas detalladamente que es lo que me esta faltando y como hacer que el código funcione.

```js
function mensaje(){
alert('hola mundo');
}
document.getElementById('Validarbtn').onclick=mensaje();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8"><!--Etiqueta para uso del caracter ñ-->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/test.js"></script>
 <title>prueba</title>
</head>
<body>
 <form action="" method="post" id="registro-frm" name="registro_frm">

  <label>
   Nombre
  <input type="text" name="nombre_txt" id="nombre"/>
  </label>
 <div>
 <button type="button" name="Validar_btn" id="Validarbtn" >Validar</button>

 </div>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Por favor considera editar y redactar un título un tanto más objetivo, pues colocar x lenguaje para principiantes no dice nada del problema que tienes

Comment: lo tendré en cuenta, gracias!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

estas haciendo mal la línea en donde atrapas el elemento.

// así debería ser

```
let variable = document.getElementById('Validarbtn');
```

// sobre ese llamar el método add event

```
variable.addEventListener('click', mensaje) ;

function mensaje(){
   alert('hola mundo');
}
```

Comment: ricardo buenas tardes lo probe pero no funciona no se que me falta, mira...

Comment: let llamada = document.getElementById('Validarbtn');
llamada.addEventListener('click',mensaje());

function mensaje(){
alert('hola mundo');
}

Answer (score 3):

La mejor forma de hacerlo con javascript puro es asociando al botón un escuchador de evento que tenga un *callback* que devuelva el mensaje. Para eso se usa un método llamado `addEventListener()`. El primer parámetro es el  tipo de evento (en este caso el click) y el segundo es el callback (una función que se pasa como parámetro y retorna algo, en este caso el mensaje):

```js
let button = document.getElementById('miboton');

button.addEventListener('click', function(){
  alert("Hola mundo");
})
```

```html
<button id='miboton'>Mensaje</button>
```

Este callback se va a ejecutar después que se escuche el evento click (cuando acciones el botón). También sirve para otros eventos como onmouseover, onkeydown, onload. Eventos que puedes ver aquí: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_events.asp

Si no entendiste mucho el vocabulario espero que esto pueda acompañar a mi respuesta:

**Functions:** https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp

**Event Listener:** https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_addeventlistener.asp

**Callbacks function:** https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/Callback_function

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, @Diesan Romero diste con la solución!!

Comment: De nada, fue un placer.

Answer (score 2):

Estas invocando a la función, el valor que le asignas a la propiedad onclick al final es el retorno de la función al invocarla con la sintaxis `mensaje()` y no el valor (la referencia de la función en si).

```
function mensaje(){
  alert('hola mundo');
}
document.getElementById('Validarbtn').onclick=mensaje;
```

Comment: Tampoco funciona david :(